# What is the regex that will return single word names with a special character that is a | (pipe)

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have words like

```
John | Gilbert | alan
Stephen | king | harris
| | Steve
Barack | | Obama
Tom | George | Stevenson 
Donald | | 
 | Alan | 
Sir | Alex | 
Stewart | | 
John | new | man
```

I would like to return single words name like below.

```
Steve
Alan
Stewart
```

I have tried

```
Name = re.search('\| (.*)',name)
```

The above re returns all of them.

Comment: Some names consist of single names others have first name last name some have first name middle name and last name, the regex should return only single names.

Comment: Does `|| Mary-Anne`, for instance, count as one or two words?

Comment: That's two words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
(?m)^(?:\|[^\S\n]*)*(\S+)[^\S\n]*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ZHGPUt/2/).

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?m)                     multiline mode (= re.M / re.MULTILINE)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\S\n]*                 any character except: non-whitespace
                             (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), '\n'
                             (newline) (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\S\n]*                 any character except: non-whitespace (all
                           but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), '\n'
                           (newline) (0 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##NU9NC4JAEL37KwbpoCZeugURRRAE0cFumTDmlovr7jJuRbD/fVu1bjPvY@Y9/TGNkgvneKcVGSAW9Ia4fMAKwjC0cFCNBAt7LirmeQsoUAYWcsN0wwaqHdQWGiTivWdG7sX8tEXCWwsDdKqww8Ba2CmJoh6xMz07DaNjMx0drW8k418HGo1hJH0QCstovSzspSzyQl6TOImKfB7/15nX@sgmIpbduaxRiOhnTmFqk/pi2TGOnfsC):**

```py
import re
string = """| John | Gilbert | alan
| Stephen | king | harris
| | Steve
| Barack | | Obama
|| Donald | | Trump 
| | Alan
| | Stewart"""
pattern = r"^(?:\|[^\S\n]*)*(\S+)[^\S\n]*$"
print(re.findall(pattern, string, re.M))
```

**Results**: `['Steve', 'Alan', 'Stewart']`

Comment: What changes are needed to the regex if the location of the single word is different as editted above

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `re.findall` with the pattern `(?:(?<=\n)|(?<=^))\|\s*\|\s*(\S+)(?:\n|$)`, which will find only single word names:

```py
inp = """| John | Gilbert | alan
| Stephen | king | harris
| | Steve
| Barack | | Obama
|| Donald | | Trump 
| | Alan
| | Stewart"""

single_names = re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\n)|(?<=^))\|\s*\|\s*(\S+)(?:\n|$)', inp)
print(single_names)
```

This prints:

```
['Steve', 'Alan', 'Stewart']
```

Comment: This returns empty lists

Comment: Is your input a _string_ or a _list_ ?  Your question does not make this clear.  My answer certainly works for the former case.

Comment: I have edited the input above can you check to see if your answer might work please.

Answer (score 1):

A *simple* modification in your existing regex pattern suffices:

```
>>> name = """
|| John Deere
|| Stephen king
|| Steve
|| Barack Hussein Obama
|| Donald Trump 
|| Alan
|| Stewart"""
>>> re.findall('\| ([^\s]*)(?:\n|$)', name)
['Steve', 'Alan', 'Stewart']
```

You can find all the matches using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) in your input string.

Edit: For your edited input containing `|` in between names, this works:

```
>>> name = """| John | Gilbert | alan
| Stephen | king | harris
| | Steve
| Barack | | Obama
|| Donald | | Trump 
| | Alan
| | Stewart"""
>>> re.findall('^[|\W]*([^\s]+)(?:\n|$)', name, re.MULTILINE)
['Steve', 'Alan', 'Stewart']
```

Comment: Your answer will fail to find the last single word name in the list should it happen to occur on the final line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^[|\s]*\|\s*([^|\s]+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[|\s]*` Match 0+ times either `|` or a whitespace char
- `\|` Match `|`
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `([^|\s]+)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except `|` or a whitspace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y0ETeT/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yv5z33)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^[|\s]*\|\s*([^|\s]+)$"

names = ("| John | Gilbert | alan\n"
            "| Stephen | king | harris\n"
            "| | Steve\n"
            "| Barack | | Obama\n"
            "|| Donald | | Trump \n"
            "| | Alan\n"
            "| | Stewart")

print(re.findall(regex, names, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['Steve', 'Alan', 'Stewart']
```

Comment: `$` might be better than `\Z`, I think.